# Prove that the empty set has outer measure zero verification

Tags: lebesgue-measure, solution-verification, outer-measure

$\forall sets A,  m^*(A) \geq 0  $

Since $m^*(\{x\})=0$ where $\{x\}$ is any singleton

and the empty set is a subset of every set

$0 \leq m^*(\emptyset) \leq m^*(\{x\})$.

Hence

$m^*(\emptyset)=0$

QED?

Comment: This is a strange proof. What is your definition of $m^{*}$? Isn't it easier to show directly from the definition that outer measure of empty set is $0$ instead of using the fact that singleton's have outer measure $0$.

Comment: you mean show the interval with containing the empty set has zero length?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477400/outer-measure-of-empty-set-is-0-using-definition-of-outer-measure